# Button group as in bootstrap css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to create a btn group class very similar to bootstrap css. I created it but i couldnt fill the gap between buttons and couldnt map the reason between the buttons.

https://jsfiddle.net/frcbn82p/

You could actually notice a small gap between the buttons. How can i remove that.

My css is

```
    .btn-group{
  display:inline-block;
}
.btn-group button{
  width:auto;

  height:40px;
  border:none;
  background-color:#4444ee;
  color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its HTML `white-space` problem on `display: inline-block;` elements so one option is to remove space in `HTML` code. Or you can set `font-size: 0` on **parent** and then again change it on **child**  [`Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/frcbn82p/2/). Or you can use comments in `HTML` [`Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/frcbn82p/4/). Or you can just use `display: flex;` [`Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/frcbn82p/6/)

```css
.btn-group{
  display:inline-block;
}

.btn-group button{
  width:auto;
  height:40px;
  border:none;
  background-color:#4444ee;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
  <button>Hello World</button><button>Hello World</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Alternatively, this will allow css to be used as a library, no need to change the user markup -- https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/frcbn82p/1/

Comment: You rocked. perfect.

Comment: Sorry, this one -- https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/frcbn82p/7/ (*last one had a problem*)

Answer (score 0):

Like said, the white-space is caused by the white-space in your actual HTML.

You can either float your `button` elements, or use `flexbox` to solve this.

---

### Floating

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/frcbn82p/3/

**CSS**

```
.btn-group{
  display:inline-block;
}
.btn-group button{
  clear: none;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width:auto;
  height:40px;
  border:none;
  background-color:#4444ee;
  color:#fff;
}
```

---

### Flexbox

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/frcbn82p/5/

**CSS**

```
.btn-group{
  display: flex;
}
.btn-group button{
  width:auto;
  height:40px;
  border:none;
  background-color:#4444ee;
  color:#fff;
}
```